# Mexican Index Mutual Funds

Tags: mutual-funds, mexico

I've seen answers here recommend index mutual funds and want to know what are some mutual funds available in my market (Mexico).  I'm interested in funds available on the Mexican stock market (BOLSA) or available in Mexico and holding BOLSA-listed securities.

Comment: http://www.cnbc.com/id/49003543 provides a partial answer but is from 2012 and it's very, very possible things have changed significantly since then. The ETF referred there, the MSCI Mexico Capped ETF, is still trading.

Comment: Is on the BOLSA?

Comment: Can you clarify: Are you looking for funds that invest in Mexican companies, or funds that are available directly on the Mexican stock market (BOLSA)?  "Mutual fund" usually refers to something that does not trade on *any* stock market, so your question in your last comment is confusing.

Comment: On Bolsa.  Mutual fund or other index fund

Answer (score 1):

The recommendations you read were, very probably, talking about US listed funds in US dollars.

The mexican Bolsa de Valores says that they list over 600 mutual funds
 so "Yes" you can invest in Mexico **using Pesos** if that is what you want.  You need a *Corredor de Bolsa* or mexico broker. [Here](http://www.svs.cl/institucional/mercados/consulta.php?mercado=V&Estado=VI&entidad=COBOL) they are.

Most international investors use exchange traded funds ETF because theirs fees are cheaper than mutual funds.  The ETF are mostly listed and traded in us stock exchange. [Here](http://etf.stock-encyclopedia.com/category/mexico-etfs.html) they are.

US mutual funds are in dollars and, because you are living in Mexico, you will have a currency risk and probably taxes.  Mexico mutual funds in Pesos do not carry any currency exposure unless the companies involved do business in the United States. You have to think about your currency exposure.

B. Veo